# Can you clean your Samsung a32 5g front and back camera lens with 70% isopropyl alcohol and a microfiber cloth?

Tags: samsung

I have the samsung a32 5g.

Will doing so cause any strappings of coatings/damage of any kind, and what are those coatings supposed to do? Are the camera lens made of plastic or glass?